# Change pie slice text on Google Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, pie-chart

I want to change the displaying of pie slice text from

---

### |  From  |

[image]

### |  To    |

[image]

I searched on Google pie chart documentation but there's no information, I try to use `legend: {position: 'labeled'}`, but is not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there's no solution with Google chart, so, I switch to this library [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo)